# which is a correct place to call API in MVVM architecture pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

which is a correct place to call API in MVVM architecture pattern ?

i have come across two kind of implementations for above scenario.

1) calling api from viewcontroller.
2) calling api from viewmodel.

which one is better suitable as per MVVM architecture ?
or any other better way from where to call api in MVVM ?

ofcourse API calls are implemented in separate web-services related classes.
but from somewhere i have to call that method (either view controller or view model)

Answer (score 5):

View: Only set view logic here such as text, color, constraints, layer etc. Super dumb.

Model: Is a Person, Book, Dog, Todo. It should only represent data in a database. Normally implements Codable etc.

View Model: The view should ask the view model for all data. So, this is where the api call is. The view should not know about the api at all.

A UIViewController, is a view and should have a viewModel. A UIViewController must still be dumb and have not idea from the API.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller acts as an intermediary between the views it manages and the data of your app
so it make more sense to call your apiCall function on the ViewController